# php select dropdown list cannot displayed some data from the database

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have created a select dropdown list where the aim consists of loading a list of association names in chronological order extracted from my database

Whenever I select an association name from the dropdown list, I would like to be able to display in textfields the corresponding address, postcode and city of the association.

With the code below, I am able to retrieve the selected association name from the dropdown list as well as the ID number of the association but after that, I don't know how to extract the other information (i.e. address, postcode, ...).

Any idea would be appreciated and/or examples would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance

```
<?php
$entry_array_ass = array ();
$entry_array_ass[0]['denomination'] = "";  // default value

$sql = "select id_association, denomination, adresse, numero, localite from association     
ORDER BY denomination";

$rs = mysql_query($sql) or die("Erreur de requ&ecirc;te : $sql");;

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($rs))
{
 extract($row);
 $entry_array_ass[$row[0]] = array ('denomination' => $row[1], 'adresse' => $row[2]);                         
}

$return_select = '<select name="list_ass" style="font-family : Verdana; font-size : 
10pt;  width:50" onchange="list_ass_handler()">';

if ( is_array ( $entry_array_ass ) ) 
{
// $K contains the key pointing to the id_association number
// $V is the array containing the denomination of each association

foreach ( $entry_array_ass as $K => $V ) 
{                             
      $return_select .= '<option value="' . $K . '"';

      // $return_select contains the list of all associations
         $return_select .= ">{$V['denomination']}</option>";              
}
}

$return_select .= "</select>";

// Display the association name
echo '<input type="hidden" name="location" id="entry_location">' . $return_select; 

// Display the ID number of the association
echo '<input type="hidden" name="id_location" id="entry_id_location">';                     
?>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: Look into Ajax.  If I understand your question, that would probably be the type of solution you would need.  On select of a dropdown item, trigger an ajax call to query your database and spit the results back into your page.